# Set Combobox Value base on another Combobox Selected Value - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have two comboboxes. If the user selects a certain value from the first combobox then I want the second combobox to automatically change and select to its corresponding value.

For example:

```
If Me.InstitutionAdvisoryFirmsComboBox1.SelectedValue = 3 Then 
     Me.WeightComboBox1.SelectedValue = 2
```

I have also tried:

```
If Me.InstitutionAdvisoryFirmsComboBox1.SelectedText = "Internal Guidelines" Then                 
    Me.WeightComboBox1.SelectedText = "None"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what SelectedValue equals? My guess is that you did not set the ValueMemeber to the thing you think you did.

Comment: What's in the box?  If they are just strings, try SelectedItem.  SelectedText is for the actual highlighted text in the displayed string.

Comment: Do the combo boxes have any items added to them prior to these lines of codes? If you do "selected text = something" that something should be added to the items prior to that line of code.

Comment: @LarsTech I tried SelectedItem and got an error stating "Conversion string "Internal Guidelines" to type Double is not valid"

Comment: @sparkysword Yes the combobox have items added prior to the code. What I did to populate the comboboxes I had to write a SQL query first since its pulling from my database and compose a code using For i ....items.add(sqltable.Rows(i)(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//selected index changed event for the combo box 

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InstitutionAdvisoryFirmsComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If Me.InstitutionAdvisoryFirmsComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then 
        If Me.WeightComboBox1.Items.Count >= 2 Then // make sure you are not accessing an index out of range
            Me.WeightComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting an error stating "InvalidArgument = Value of 2 is not valide for SelectedIndex.

Comment: Do you have 3 items in the combo box?

Comment: Yes I have 3 items in my second comobox. Exactly 3 items

Comment: What happens when you run this code with the extra if statement?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the event handler for the `comboBox` that you are checking. Inside the event handler you can use a slight variation of your if statement:

```
If Me.InstitutionAdvisoryFirmsComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then                 
    Me.WeightComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2
```

When using the `SelectedIndex` function, the counting starts at the 0th position.

When Using `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` is used for getting that text or value inside the `combobox`.

```
Dim ComboValue As String = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

or

```
Dim ComboValue As String = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: I have already tried that as another user suggested it earlier, however i got an error stating "InvalidArgument = Value of 2 is not valid for SelectedIndex."

Comment: I have 3 items. I want to select the third item, therefore I put SelectedIndex = 2