# How to change value in combobox depending on the selected item in other combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Can anyone help me how to change value in ComboBox depending on the selected item in other ComboBox using vb.net? Beginner here :)

I have tried searching on youtube, but it only displays tutorial in C#, Java, etc but not VB.net.

Comment: I suspect that you haven't actually asked the question that you want answered.  Are you saying that you want the list of items in one `ComboBox` to change based on the selection in another? If so then you need to explain what the relationship is between the data. Is it two `DataTables` populated from the same database? Is it something else and, if so, what is it?  By the way, anything you find in C# will be relevant to VB as well. You will make use of all the same types, properties, methods and events, with just the syntax changing slightly.

Comment: I tried searching using the criteria `change value in combobox depending on other combobox vb.net` and found several results, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184896/set-combobox-value-base-on-another-combobox-selected-value-vb-net.  Also, to improve the quality of your Question, please include the code that you have been trying and the full text of any error messages it produces.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realized how I asked the question.

Comment: But thank you! Next time, I will make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

i'm beginner too, so CMIIW

First add item from ComboBox1 to ComboBox2 Then
select ComboBox2 item as ComboBox1 item selected

Try this :

Double click on ComboBox1, then :

`ComboBox2.Items.Add(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
 ComboBox2.SelectedItem = ComboBox1.SelectedItem`